# Rspec 3: can't check class type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Observe:

```
class BaseValidator; end
class DefaultValidator < BaseValidator; end
```

Rspec 3.1:

```
describe ValidatorFactory do
    context "creating DefaultValidator" do
        subject { ValidatorFactory.validator('default') }
        it {is_expected.to be_a(DefaultValidator)}
        it {is_expected.to be_kind_of(BaseValidator) }
    end
end
```

Prints me this:

```
Failure/Error: it {is_expected.to be_a(DefaultValidator)}
   expected DefaultValidator to be a kind of DefaultValidator

Failure/Error: it {is_expected.to be_kind_of(BaseValidator) }
   expected DefaultValidator to be a kind of BaseValidator
```

However, this works:

```
...
    it {is_expected.to be(DefaultValidator)}
    it {is_expected.to be < (BaseValidator) }
...
```

ValidatorFactory.rb

```
class ValidatorFactory
    def self.validator(type)
    case type.downcase
    when 'default'
        DefaultValidator
    else
        BaseValidator
    end
end
```

Now, I could not find anythyng about be() and be < for class type maching in RSpec docs.

Am I using "be_a" and "be_kind_of" in a wrong way?

Comment: It would help to see the implementation of `ValidatorFactory.validator`.  See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers for documentation of the two matchers that failed.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, added implementation of ValidatorFactory.validator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your validator method is returning the **class** `DefaultValidator` and/or `BaseValidator`.
In other words, those are not instances of those classes, but their class is `Class`.

The `be_a` and `be_a_kind_of` [matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/type-check-matchers) are for asserting that an object is an **instance** of the Class or Module argument that is passed to them.

That's why your first code sample fails, but the second one passes. The second code snippet is testing `Class` instances, not instances of your validator.